# Best program to trim silence beginning and end of mp3 files?

Tags: software-rec, mp3, trim

I have a bunch of mp3 files that have silence at the beginnings and ends, is there any program to trim this automatically? I would prefer that I can just give it a list of files to trim as opposed to having to do them individually.

Comment: windows? linux? macos?

Comment: windows for me, but answers for others are fine.

Comment: Simple and best solution is [Batch-Audio-Silence-Remover](http://download.cnet.com/Batch-Audio-Silence-Remover)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[dBpoweramp Music Converter (dMC)](http://www.dbpoweramp.com/dmc.htm) is free and can batch process audio files and has a [DSP Effects](http://www.dbpoweramp.com/dbpoweramp-dsp.htm) plugin which includes:

> [image: Trim Silence] **Trim Silence**: remove silence from beginning or end

Comment: do you know if this works with the free version?

Comment: I believe so...

Comment: Worked great for me!

Comment: [dBpoweramp Music Converter (dMC)](http://www.dbpoweramp.com/dmc.htm) is really complicated software. And it didn't for for me aswell. Simple and best solution is 

[Batch-Audio-Silence-Remover](http://download.cnet.com/Batch-Audio-Silence-Remover/3000-2170_4-76170354.html?tag=bc)

Comment: does it work with wav files too?

Comment: @BRHSM yep, it does work with wav files.

Comment: This 100% absolutely does not work.  It doesn't work with default setting of -45 decibels (uh, negative 45 decibels?), with a db rating of 5, 50, 100, 1000, -1000, or with a threshold match of 50 ms (default), 10 ms, 25 ms, -25 ms, or -100 ms.  Every setting has the same exact effect: NONE.

Answer (score 4):

In Audacity there's a Nyquist plugin called Trim Silence, download it here: http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=59370

However, it can't be used for batch processing :-(

This effect requires Audacity 1.3.8 or later.

Although you cant batch process them you can import many files at once as if you are working on a multi track project, then process them with this plugin and finally re-export them as separate files.

To do this follow the following menu options after ensuring the Trim Silence plugin is installed properly.
1) File - Import - Audio (choose files to process)
2) Effect - Trim Silence (set options)
3) File - Export Multiple (choose options for saving files)

Comment: Audacity relies on LAME for outputting to mp3. Lame is the cause of the silence that needs to be removed. So using audacity to remove silence from mp3s and then exporting to mp3 leaves you at square one.

Comment: @JoelHarris That is not entirely the case. When you import an MP3 in Audacity, it considers the padded silence as part of the Audio whereas LAME enabled players are programmed to skip this silence. When you re-export the imported MP3 from Audacity, it again wraps the whole audio (including the padded silence from the import) into yet another layer of padded silence. Now, this gap will be audible in LAME enabled players as well.

Comment: For anyone in the future, silence padded by the LAME encoding can be removed using ffmpeg. Use ffmpeg to convert your MP3 to the raw PCM audio and then import in Audacity.

Answer (score 3):

[mpTrim](http://www.mptrim.com/) seems to be just what you want:

> What exactly can mpTrim do for you?
>
> - mpTrim can trim MP3s - removing silent or unwanted parts.
> - mpTrim can adjust the volume of MP3s. Volume change can be manual
>     or automatic (volume normalization).
> - mpTrim can fade-in/out MP3s (to fix abrupt beginning/ending).
> - mpTrim can clean-up MP3s and recover wasted disk space.
> - mpTrim keeps the music quality intact, no matter how many times you
>     process an MP3, because it works directly in the MP3 format without
>     having to decode/re-encode. That also makes it very fast.

*mpTrim is free - no evaluation period or time limit. I'm just not sure about it having batch capabilities.*

[image]

Comment: mp3 trim works like a charm, but the free version only allows you to do one file at a time. A real pain if you have tons of stuff, trust me, your arm will ache. Just for the fun of it I downloaded a whole whack of Karaoke mp3 and most had 13 seconds of silence at the end and the beginning. Had to stop editing after awhile, just to much stress on the arm doing this after awhile. Only got a few now and then, use it. I saw a post at MP3 direct cut and somebody stated the only way software can automatically detect silence is if you use a cue sheet. Duh, mp3 trim has the option to find silence auto

Comment: Free version has 7 minute time limit for songs

Comment: Yes, only the paid version has batch capabilities