# How to create MP3 from WAV without silence at the start and end?

Tags: audio, software-rec, mp3, wav, audio-conversion

I´m creating MP3 files from WAV in FL Studio. But in created MP3 file is a very short silence (for example 0.02 sec) at the beginning and at the end of the file.

In my program, I want to merge these MP3 files one after another but with this silence the result is an MP3 with silence between tracks.

How do I create the MP3 file from WAV without silence? I need to create MP3 from WAV (maybe use another format?) and merge/join these files.

Or exists program to trim this short silence (<0.1 sec)? Do you have someone experience with this?

P.S. I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/400790/covert-wav-to-mp3-without-adding-silence-at-the-beginning) but it´s not helpful for my needs. Maybe there is a new solution (post is a little old).

Comment: If you use `audacity` as your audio editor you can merge all the WAV files in the GUI and control the spacing - you can remove silences pre-existing in the source files and export a single MP3 when you are happy with the result. This should maintain the best quality, as there is only a single conversion. Of course there are many other audio editors, but `audacity` is freeware and multi-platform, and I have found it handles large files well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Covert WAV to MP3 without adding silence at the beginning](http://superuser.com/questions/400790/covert-wav-to-mp3-without-adding-silence-at-the-beginning)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best program to trim silence beginning and end of mp3 files?](https://superuser.com/questions/120315/best-program-to-trim-silence-beginning-and-end-of-mp3-files)

Answer (score 1):

[dBpoweramp Music Converter (dMC)](http://www.dbpoweramp.com/dmc.htm) is free and can batch process audio files and has a DSP Effects plugin which includes:

```
   Trim Silence: remove silence from beginning or end
```

Found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/120315/best-program-to-trim-silence-beginning-and-end-of-mp3-files).

Comment: There is still a small silence.