# How to trim an audio clip?

Tags: software-rec, audio-recording

I'm trying to record the sounds of different English syllables to test an algorithm, but the audio usually ends up getting *long* with unnecessary quiet (empty) *spaces* at the beginning and end.

Is there any software that can help me trim those *empty spaces*? Thanks.

Comment: automatically ?

Comment: preferably, yes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually trim the audio with Audacity. [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) can remove Clicks and Noises automatically, but I'm not sure if it can trim automatically (with Nyquist plugin called Trim Silence it is possible).

> About Audacity
>
> Audacity is a free, easy-to-use and multilingual audio editor and
>   recorder for Windows, Mac OS X, GNU/Linux and other operating systems.
>   You can use Audacity to:
>
> Record live audio. Convert tapes and records into digital recordings
>   or CDs. Edit Ogg Vorbis, MP3, WAV or AIFF sound files. Cut, copy,
>   splice or mix sounds together. Change the speed or pitch of a
>   recording. And more! See the complete list of features.

EDIT: [Possible duplicate can be found here...](https://superuser.com/questions/120315/best-program-to-trim-silence-beginning-and-end-of-mp3-files)

> In Audacity there's a Nyquist plugin called Trim Silence, download it
>   here: http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=59370

Other possible solutions(from the above link):

mpTrim & dBpoweramp Music Converter (dMC)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I should have done more search. I just found this online:

[MP3 Trimby Logiccell](http://download.cnet.com/MP3Trim/3000-2169_4-10026746.html)

*Publisher's Description:*

> MP3Trim is a utility that allows you to trim MP3 music files. Useful
>   on files that contain unwanted sounds at the beginning or end, MP3Trim
>   works by trimming precisely at MPEG frame increments. It can
>   automatically detect digital silence and recover wasted disk space
>   occupied by silent frames. In addition, it recognizes ID3 tags and
>   cleans up missing or incomplete frames and WAV headers (for
>   WAV-embedded MP3s). This version features a better error message when
>   the disk gets full, changes the default threshold for normalization to
>   -3dB, which gives a little volume headroom for the tracks with wide dynamic ranges, and contains an added check for tracks that end
>   abruptly.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17932/how-can-you-trim-mp3-files-using-ffmpeg --but specifically for "text-mode" tools to be run from the command prompt.  The answers there may be helpful, though they were intended for Linux, I've also used them successfully under Windows since some of those commands have been compiled for win32.

For a pure Windows solution, I've also used a program called GoldWave which is available as a try-before-you-buy download (it seemed fully functional to me, not crippled).  To split the file in GoldWave, click Tools, then Cue points then Auto cue then Time split and choose a time interval then click split.