# How can I export seamless MP3 to loop without gaps?

Tags: audio, mp3, audacity

I opened a 10-second MP3 in Audacity that has a 0.05-second silent gap at the beginning and the end of the clip. I removed this silent space and exported it again as MP3. The problem is that when I play it on loop in Firefox and Chrome, I can still hear a quick gap when it repeats. So I open my trimmed file in Audacity, and the gap is back! It looks like it gets added during the export process.

**Start of the file:**
[image]

**End of the file:**
[image]

I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/938848/888753) that links to best programs to trim silence. The problem is that I can already trim the silence myself manually, what I need is an MP3 exporter that doesn't add it back!

Comment: If you are on Windows I would try [MP3DirectCut](https://mpesch3.de/)

Comment: Are you cutting at a zero-crossing? idk Audacity really, but if you don't cut at zero you'll get a click. Some apps will try to prevent that for you. If you have DC offset in the signal, that could confuse any similar algorithm. [Your zoom is far too low to be able to see any non-zero or offset visually]